# foreach loop in a form with database table data, change the data and update the database in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, forms

I'm building a wordpress plugin for fun, and I want something crazy, I think.

1. make a form with a foreach loop with an entire database table.
2. change the data of the whole database table
3. update the database data of this table

I've got this until now, but I'm stuck when I want to update the records.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_hidden" value="Y">
<table>
<tbody>
        <?php 
        global $wpdb;
        $post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY id ASC"); 
        foreach($post_id as $row){ 
        echo    '<tr><td>' . $row->id . '</td><td><input type="text" name="' . $row->name . '" value="' . $row->name . '" /></td></tr>';
        }

        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update Options" />
</form>


<?php


if($_POST['form_hidden'] == 'Y') {
    //update database
    global $wpdb;

        foreach($_POST['name'] as $item){
                $wpdb->replace( 'tbl_name',  ); // <- some kind of array here
        }


}
```

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues, I guess.

1. wpdb::replace(...) replaces the columns of all rows with ONE value;
   that is not what you want, correct?
2. To update the correct row in your table, you should refer to the corresponding primary key. I guess "id" in your case.
3. To store multiple values in your form as an "array", you have to use field names like "name[]".

Lets put it all together:

```
// in your form creation loop...
foreach($post_id as $row){ 
    echo '<tr><td><input type="text" name="id[]" value="' . $row->id . '" /></td><td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="' . $row->name . '" /></td></tr>';
}

// processing the new values
foreach($_POST['id'] as $I => $id) {
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE tbl_name SET name=%s where id=%d"
        , $_POST['name'][$I]
        , $id
        );
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

These are only the interesting parts - just combine it with your existing code. See

Useful links:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/

https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Good luck!